# R Write a dbf file

Tags: r, data-analysis

I want to create a `dbf` file to export a data frame to, I already tried:

```
write.dbf(MyDF,MyDF.dbf,factor2char = F)
```

but get the error code:

> Error in write.dbf(MyDF, MyDF.dbf, factor2char = F) :
>     object 'MyDF.dbf' not found

I can tell why but I just can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd parameter should be a string.  Try this:

```
write.dbf(MyDF,"MyDF.dbf",factor2char = F)
```

The error you are getting is that MyDF.dbf is being treated as a variable name and you haven't defined a variable with that name.